# App still accessible at reverse proxied port

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, port-forwarding, apache2

I am running RStudio Server and Jupyter on a server. I'm using Apache.

I have Jupyter reverse proxied from port 8888 to jupyter.myserver.com, and RStudio Server reverse proxied form port 8787 to rstudio.myserver.com. I cannot access jupyter at myserver.com:8888. However, I CAN access RStudio Server at myserver.com:8787.

I'm using the same reverse proxy format for both.

If I add `listen 80` at the top of my `.conf` file, I get the error:

> Cannot define multiple Listeners on the same IP:port

1) What is the reason?
2) How do I prevent the url:port access for Rstudio?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@myserver.com
        ServerName jupyter.myserver.com
        ServerAlias jupyter.myserver.com
        ProxyRequests Off

        <Location />
                ProxyPreserveHost On
                ProxyPass http://localhost:8787/
                ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8787/
        </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You can't `listen 80` because you already have that in your configuration.

Comment: I'm guessing that's what the error is about.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552316-Configuring-the-Server), configure RStudio to listen on the loopback address 127.0.0.1 instead of the server's IP address, so it will only accept local connections (e.g. from Apache on the same server):

> Network Port and Address After initial installation RStudio accepts
>   connections on port 8787. If you wish to change to another port you
>   should create an /etc/rstudio/rserver.conf file (if one doesn't
>   already exist) and add a www-port entry corresponding to the port you
>   want RStudio to listen on. For example:
>
> `www-port=80`
>
> **By default RStudio binds to address 0.0.0.0 (accepting
>   connections from any remote IP)**. You can modify this behavior using
>   the www-address entry. For example:
>
> `www-address=127.0.0.1`
>
> Note that after editing the
>   /etc/rstudio/rserver.conf file you should always restart the server to
>   apply your changes (and validate that your configuration entries were
>   valid). You can do this by entering the following command:
>
> $ sudo rstudio-server restart

Or, turn the server's firewall on and block incoming connections on all ports except 22 (SSH) and 80 (Apache).